# To sightsee ...or ..to go sightseeing?

Tags: british-english

How common is it, nowadays, to say that  one 'sightsees', rather than 'goes sightseeing'?

Comment: Do you mean in written English, or spoken English?

Answer (score 1):

According to Google NGrams people have been writing about *sightseeing* since the end of the 18th century, but have only used *sightsee* since the beginning of the 20th century:

[image: Google ngram of sightsee vs sightseeing 1780n - 2000]

As can be seen, *sightseeing* is more popular. However in the context you mention, *to sightsee* is fairing better:

[image: Google ngram of "to sightsee" vs "to go sightseeing" 1800 - 2000]

While "to go sightseeing" is less popular in British English than "to sightsee", there has been a fair amount of variation over the last few decades.

So, in answer to your question: "sightsee" is a bit more popular, but not much and not stably.

Comment: One more [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sightsee%2Cgo+sightseeing&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csightsee%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsightsee%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSightsee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgo%20sightseeing%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgo%20sightseeing%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGo%20sightseeing%3B%2Cc0): "sightsee" vs. "go sightseeing" 1960 through 2008

Answer (score 0):

I think "sightseeing" is much better that "sightsees". Because you can got to sighting when ever you want but sight sighs is like it is for a particular moment.